# Find a cut in graph that divides the graph to approximately equal two subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Is there a practical algorithm (not NP-hard) that can cut a graph into two *approximately* equal sub-graphs (e.g., One sub-graph has 40%-50% vertices), in the meantime, prove that the cut is the minimal possible cut given the condition that two sub-graphs have approximately equal number of vertices?

Comment: Closely related problem is [Sparsest cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29#Sparsest_cut). And it is NP-Hard.

Comment: If you want approximately, greedy and/or hill climbing is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not exactly sparsest cut; it's balanced cut, also NP-hard, as described in [Chapter 8 of Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap8.pdf). The canonical version of the sparsest cut problem does not allow specification of the partition size.

There are two streams of research on graph partitioning problems: algorithms with worst-case approximation guarantees, of which Arora–Rao–Vazirani is the main result of interest to you, and algorithms without worst-case guarantees, which are evaluated by their practical performance (random example I have no experience with: [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview)). Even though I don't know it very well, I'd be inclined to steer you toward the latter line of work; a priori, O(√log n) bicriteria approximation is just not a very useful guarantee, and there's likely to be some nontrivial algorithms engineering to get ARV working well at scale in the first place.